# How to manage datasets in ClearML Web UI?

Tags: clearml, trains

Using a self-deployed ClearML server with the clearml-data CLI, I would like to manage (or view) my datasets in the WebUI as shown on the ClearML webpage (https://clear.ml/mlops/clearml-feature-store/):

[image: ClearML feature store]

However, this feature does not show up in my Web UI. According to the pricing page, the feature store is not a premium feature. Do I need to configure my server in a special way to use this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm part of the ClearML (formerly Trains) Team

I think this screenshot is taken from the premium version...
The feature itself exists in the open-source version, but I "think" some of the dataset visualization capabilities are not available in the open-source self hosted version.

Nonetheless, you have a fully featured feature-store, with the ability to add your own metrics / samples for every dataset/feature version. The open-source version also includes the advanced versioning & delta based storage for datasets/features (i.e. only the change set from the parent version is stored)